# Windows 10 inside VirtualBox not scaling after upgrade from 8.1

Tags: virtualbox, upgrade, windows-10

I installed VirtualBox on my host windows.

Inside I have windows 8.1. I decided to do an upgrade check. The check informed me that the following devices were incompatible: VirtualBox Graphics Adapter for Windows 8 driver.

Given that I know it should work, I decided to ignore the warning and go ahead with the upgrade. The upgrade works and I have display, but the guest addons won't recognize it properly, as I cannot use the auto-scale guest function. I installed the guest addons and updated the drivers but nothing helps.

I know its not optimal as windows feels sluggish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your `control panel` -> `system` -> `Device manager` and remove the display driver: `Display adapters` -> `VirtualBox Graphics Adapter for Windows 8`:

1. Right click the adapter and choose `Uninstall`
2. Check the `[v] Delete the driver software for this device`.
3. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>

Reboot windows and it will install `Windows basic graphics adapter`

Now, install the guests addons again, and reboot the pc when it does so.

The guest addons will correctly convert the graphics adapter and after a minute or so with the new driver, the `Auto scale guest` function will scale the screen properly. In addition it will work correctly as it did in windows 8 and is not sluggish.