# Windows 10 much slower than Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and overall I’m noticing Windows 10 is a lot slower than Windows 8.1 in the same tasks!

I run Windows using Parallels in a Macbook Core i7 with 16GB of RAM, so processing power is not a problem.

I kept the older Windows 8.1 machine and both have the same apps. If I open both machines at the same time, the overall speed difference is very noticeable.

Already disabled Windows defender and I don’t use any antivirus.

I'm about to go back to Windows 8.1. Is there anything i could do to improve Windows 10 performance? Is there anything that could cause such speed difference?

Comment: Did you upgrade your windows 8 to windows 10? if so, its possible that the slow downs are causing by a not properly installed graphics card. I had the same. Had to uninstall and remove the graphicscard driver so it reverted back to windows basic driver, then run the guest addons again.

Comment: I upgraded from Windows 8.1, not Windows 8... does it make any difference ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the .1, but yeah, I meant that.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/951818/windows-10-inside-virtualbox-not-scaling-after-upgrade-from-8-1

Comment: In my case i use Parallels, not Virtualbox... could it has the same issue ?

Comment: Of course. Parallels, VirtualBox, VMWare, they're all virtual machines and all work using the same principle. They use internal emulated hardware, and their installers come with the program as you install it. Other hardware is available through windows update, and as such the upgrade provides for new drivers. It tries to do that in the upgrade too but fails. As such it feels sluggish and reacts slow. Fix the graphicscard drivers and it'll go fast again. I'm almost certain. Windows 10 should perform the same or better than 8.1 You can follow the uninstall procedure from that link.

Comment: I just saw that the Parallels Display Adapter is currently not compatible with Windows 10 ; there are a lot of complains out there. I will wait for an update and then test it again. Thanks !

Comment: Try the windows 8 driver. It might work. In windows 10 oracle also uses their windows 8 driver. You may need to run the installer as windows 8 compatible mode.

Comment: Windows 10 is cool, but no doubt it works slower than previous versions of windows and takes more memory (at least from my experience and from what I hear from others).